# How to reload the whole UIViewController page

Tags: ios, swift

I want to reload my `UIViewController` after I return back from another `UIViewController`

In my `ReviewController` I have this code to open the `WriteReviewController`

```swift
let newViewController = WriteReviewController()
navigationController?.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In my `WriteReviewController`, I use

```swift
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to return back to the `ReviewController`. 
I want to make the `ReviewController` to reload page so that the new review can show up on the page. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's `UIViewController`, not `UIController`.
Secondly - it depends if you have to pass data *back*  from your `WriteReviewController` or not.

1. If yes, you need to create a protocol with a function to pass back the new review.
2. If you simply want to reload your data model for the `ReviewController`, you can simply do your reloading logic in `viewWillAppear(animated:)` function, inherited by `UIViewController`.

Let me know which way you need further help with and I can help you with writing the code.

---

EDIT: I'm pretty sure answer 1 is correct, so here's some help:

```swift
// assuming you have a struct like this for your Review data model
struct Review {
    var reviewText: String
    var author: String
}

// add this code to your ReviewController
protocol WriteReviewDelegate: class {
    func newReviewHasBeenWritten(_ review: Review)
}
class ReviewController: UIViewController {
    // ...
}
// make that ReviewController conform to this class
extension ReviewController: WriteReviewDelegate {
    func newReviewHasBeenWritten(_ review: Review) {
        // save the review to your model here
        // afterwards, update your UI to show the new review
    }
}

// add the following code to your WriteReviewController
class WriteReviewController {
    weak var delegate: WriteReviewDelegate?

    func saveReview() {
        // called when the user wants to  save a new review
        // notify the delegate (your ReviewController), that there's a new Review
        self.delegate?.newReviewHasBeenWritten(self.review)
        // then dismiss it, for example
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: @WPN did that help you?